# Multiple Choice questions - check valid answer on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, flask

I am working on a multiple choice question form.  I am using Flask on the back-end and MySQL as a database. The structure of the `question` table is the following [image]

- There will be more than 1 end-user. I already made a `users` table but haven't work on it yet
- There are multiple questions but I only display one question at once.
- Every question have either 3 or 4 possible choices (A, B, C or A, B, C, D)
- There is always one correct answer
- When the user select an answer, he can try as much as he wants to until he got the correct answer
- If the user click on a correct answer, the answer will have a green background, otherwise red.
- However, I would use the answer selected during the first try and store the result for the user own statistics

**What would be the best and clean way to check if the user selection is the correct answer? And I am still unable to pass my correct answer to my JS file. The correct asnwer is present at `row[6]` under the html**

**main.py (flask)**

```
@app.route('/questions')
def questions():
    sql = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE question_id = 9" # 9 is a temporary value, it will be a random after
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql)
    question_data = cursor.fetchall()
    print(question_data)
    return render_template("questions.html", data=question_data)
```

value of `data` is `(9, 4, 'What programming language does Facebook use?', 'C#', 'Python', 'PHP', 'Java', 'C')`

`row[2]` is the question
`row[3:5]` are the questions
`row[6]` is the correct answer

**questions.html**

```
    <section id="question">
        <div class="container-1">
            {% for row in data %}
            <p>{{row}}</p>
            {% endfor %}

            {% for row in data %}
            <h3 id="question-text">{{row[2]}}</h3>
            <ul id="question-options">
                <li class="question-answer" onclick="checkAnswer(this, 'A')">{{row[3]}}</li>
                <li class="question-answer" onclick="checkAnswer(this, 'B')">{{row[4]}}</li>
                <li class="question-answer" onclick="checkAnswer(this, 'C')">{{row[5]}}</li>
            </ul>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </section>
<script src="../static/scripts/app.js"></script>
```

**app.js**

```
let correctAnswer = 'C'
function checkAnswer(divSelected, selectedAnswer){
  if(selectedAnswer == correctAnswer){
    divSelected.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  }
  else{
    divSelected.style.backgroundColor = "red";

  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to do it in that way

**questions.Html**

```
   {% for row in data %}
    <h3 id="question-text">{{row[2]}}</h3>
    <ul id="question-options">
        <li class="question-answer" onclick='checkAnswer(this, "A", `{{row[7]}}`)'>{{row[3]}}</li>
        <li class="question-answer" onclick='checkAnswer(this, "B", `{{row[7]}}`)'>{{row[4]}}</li>
        <li class="question-answer" onclick='checkAnswer(this, "C", `{{row[7]}}`)'>{{row[5]}}</li>
    </ul>
    {% endfor %}
```

**app.js**

```
function checkAnswer(divSelected, selectedAnswer, correctAnswer){
  console.log(correctAnswer)
  console.log(selectedAnswer)

  if(selectedAnswer == correctAnswer){
    divSelected.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  }
  else{
    divSelected.style.backgroundColor = "red";

  }
}
```